# How to multiply polynomials in scilab

Tags: scilab

It´s supposed there is, at least, two comands, poly and var. But I don´t know how to use them to perform a operation like this:

1/4*b*a^2 - a*b/2(2/3*a)^2

where a y b are symbolic variables.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Scilab's symbolic capabilities extend to multiple variables. You can create polynomials in one variable using `poly`, e.g.

```
-->p = poly([1 2 3], 'x', 'c')
p  =

               2  
    1 + 2x + 3x
```

and can create polynomials in another variable similarly but if you try to combine them it gives an error. You can multiply polynomials by constants and by variables whose contents are numeric but this doesn't help in your situation.

The symbolic features of Scilab are geared towards rational fractions and the kind of Z-transform operations used for pole/zero calculations in filter design but for more complicated symbolic maths like this you could perhaps look at Mathematica (commercial, though home licenses are fairly reasonable if that's applicable).

Answer (score 1):

Given `p = 2x^2 + 3x + 4` and `q = 5x + 7`

```
<enter code here> p=[2 3 4];
<enter code here> q=[5 7];
<enter code here> answer=convol(p,q);
<enter code here> disp(answer)
```